# ROBOCOPY, What is the meaning of "mismatch" and "failed"

Tags: robocopy

Anyone could please clarify what's the meaning of the columns `MISMATCH` and `FAILED` in the Run summary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Failed` means the copying process of a file should have but did not work. `Mismatch` means that the source is a directory and the (existing) target is a file (or vice versa).

Source: Robocopy.doc ([here](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=ZGVmYXVsdGRvbWFpbnx2b2xpdmVpcmFwfGd4OjFiOWY2ZGQwOGFiMzI3MTQ) and [here](http://mclaveau.com/gvrac/robo.html) as an external link, I can't find the official MS link at the moment) on page 15 (first link) refers to the source being a file and the target being a directory. Few pages down you get the specific explanations:

`Mismatch (File Tag): The source file corresponds to a destination directory of the same name. The source file is skipped, and housekeeping of the destination tree is recommended.`

`Mismatch (Directory Tag): This source directory corresponds to a destination file of the same name and cannot be processed. Housekeeping of the destination is recommended.`

**What this means for the copying process:**

`Failed` is an error meaning not all files were copied. Uncopied files will result in a return code 8 and higher. `Mismatch` is error code 4-7 (actually just 4, 5-7 are combination of 4 with another code). To my understanding all the (different) files were copied (assuming you use the purge switch, without the switch mismatches will be skipped).

I would save a detailed log and see what file/dir the mismatch applies to.

In the return codes you'll find:

```
Value   Description
4       Mismatched files or directories were detected.  Examine the log file for more information.
5       Some files were copied. Some files were mismatched. No failure was encountered.
6       Additional files and mismatched files exist. No files were copied and no failures were encountered. This means that the files already exist in the destination directory.
7       Files were copied, a file mismatch was present, and additional files were present.
```

See [here (ss64)](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy-exit.html) or [here (MS)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/backup-and-storage/return-codes-used-robocopy-utility) or [here (MS)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) or [here (blog)](https://adamtheautomator.com/robocopy/#Common_Robocopy_Syntax_Reference) for error code sources.

Here's the info on the purge tag:

> Maintaining True Replication
>
> If you require the destination directory tree to be maintained as an
> exact mirror of the source directory tree, you must delete files and
> directories from the destination whenever they disappear from the
> source. To accomplish this, use the /E and /PURGE switches in
> combination, or use the /MIR switch
>
> The /PURGE switch causes Robocopy to delete all Extra and Mismatched
> destination files and directories. After a Mismatched destination
> entry has been deleted, the corresponding source entry is then treated
> as a Lonely file or directory and processed accordingly. When /PURGE
> results in the deletion of an Extra or Mismatched destination
> directory, the entire directory tree, including all subordinate files
> and subdirectories, is deleted (even if /S or /E is not specified).

PS: I just answered this question: [Any way to make Robocopy produce “failed” and “mismatched” files for testing purposes?](https://superuser.com/questions/1651432/any-way-to-make-robocopy-produce-failed-and-mismatched-files-for-testing-pur/1651445#1651445), if you need to reproduce failed and mismatched.

Comment: Were these the man pages you were trying to find: [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) | [TechNet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/52831.robocopy-complete-reference.aspx)

Comment: @JW0914 thx, but unfortunately no, that page doesn't contain the required info about mismatch (I already linked to that page in my answer, see 2nd MS link)

Comment: Thanks a lot, clarified.  What would I do without you guys.