# Any way to make Robocopy produce "failed" and "mismatched" files for testing purposes?

Tags: robocopy

I'm learning Robocopy and I'd like to find a way to produce a Run summary with `Failed` and `Mismatched` files or folders.

I guess you cannot produce a Failed result unless you have a hard drive with bad sectors or similar?

Comment: Please don't double post questions - this is a part of your other question "[ROBOCOPY, What is the meaning of “mismatch” and “failed”](https://superuser.com/questions/1651430/robocopy-what-is-the-meaning-of-mismatch-and-failed)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `failed` can be easily reproduced by used a network drive as a target (disconnect the network), `mismatched` can be reproduced by creating a file on the target that has the same name as a directory on the source (or vice versa).

I just answered this question: [ROBOCOPY, What is the meaning of “mismatch” and “failed”](https://superuser.com/questions/1651430/robocopy-what-is-the-meaning-of-mismatch-and-failed/1651433#1651433), if you need more info on failed and mismatched.

Comment: Impressive, Super-Thanks!  However, I noticed that Mismatched files/folders aren't counted in the log summary, I wonder if mismatches are ever counted there.
I managed to get Failed results by trying to copy offine files from Onedrive from a system drive connected externally.

Comment: @Antonio23249 what "log summary" do you mean? the regular summary at the end of the process? If so you might have used the wrong switch or s.th. else, I just tested it and it behaves as expected.

Comment: I mean the columns at bottom of the log counting Total, Copied, Skipped, Mismatch, Failed, Extras...the Mismatch column always shows 0 even if there were mismatches found and listed in the log (I created a file in source with the same name as a folder in target).

Comment: Sorry, I can not replicate the error using the current Robocopy version in Win10. It might be a bug but in my experience in most cases it's user error. You might want to create a follow up question including the exact setup, command and possibly screenshots.